# How is it possible for lightdm to auto login without using a tty?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I can configure lightdm to auto login to my Debian distro and start the X server. However, when I switch to one of the ttys, I have to log in again. How is this possible? If I don't use lightdm, I can configure systemd to auto log in as well by editing getty@tty1.service. But that logs in using a tty.
Also, the ACL permissions on some of the /dev/input/eventX devices are retained when lightdm logs in even though only the X server is logged in. This all works great and as anyone would expect, but I don't understand magic of how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Login sessions and ttys are separate concepts.  It might seem otherwise, as historically, there was no other way to log in except through a tty.

tty is a text terminal.  Lightdm only deals with graphical terminals, so it is unrelated.  If you open a text terminal inside your graphics session, it gets a tty, but that doesn't equate to a login -- mutiple ttys won't show up in last as multiple logins. or show up at all.

Comment: Would it be possible then for me to create my own login session, say as a systemd service, to login user xyz and then launch some binary under the same user? All without a tty?

Comment: You are mixing up different things.  Yes, you can make a systemd service, but it isn't a login session.  You can run binaries automatically several ways with or without a tty without a login session.  You only need a tty if you need a text terminal.  It isn't clear to me if you need a login session either.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was run a binary under a particular user using systemd. Not logging in necessarily. What I want is to run one binary in a "kiosk" setup, but the binary requires the X server because it needs an OpenGL graphics context. What would be great if systemd could just handle all this, start the X server, then the binary that relies on X and the GPU driver, and that's it.